# Python & Pygame - Update Select Statement to move objects

Tags: python, mysql, pygame

Disclaimer: I am by no means an expert at coding in Python or using Pygame.

I am populating my screen with objects from a MySQL database. These objects have various attributes, obviously the image, width, height, x & y etc. They appear when I run my script.

However, when I update the values of these in the table, I would expect them to change while my script is running. Here is the code I'm currently running:

```
def get_object():
    cursor1 = database.mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
    cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM objects")

    myresult1 = cursor1.fetchall()

    for x in myresult1:
        img = pygame.image.load('assets\objects' + x[1])
        display.blit(img, (x[3], x[4]))
        print(x[3])


def refresh():
    get_object()
    pygame.display.update()
```

I am calling refresh on a simple key down for now (it will eventually be timed to automatically be called)

```
def main_loop():
    pygame.event.clear()
    while not g_exit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    refresh()

        display.fill(colors.goldenrod)
        main_window()
        avatar(display_width / 2, main_window_height + 10)
        chat_window()
        controls_window()
        pygame.display.update()


main_loop()
```

Like I say, the objects appear on screen fine, and when I update the values, close and re-run, they appear in the new location. I just can't for the life of me get them to update while the script is running.

Answer (score 1):

Just think of what your code does step for step:

- In your main loop, it checks if `K_LEFT` is pressed.
- If yes, it calls `refresh()`
- `refresh()` calls `get_object()`
- `get_object()` does the database query and draws stuff to the screen
- `refresh()` updates the screen with the new changes by calling `pygame.display.update()`
- It's all done in vain, because as it returns to the main loop, the very next step is to fill the entire screen with `display.fill(colors.goldenrod)`
- now your screen is just a solid color

You could restructure your code like this, for example:

```
def get_objects():
    cursor1 = database.mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
    cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM objects")

    return cursor1.fetchall()

def draw_objects(display, myresult1):
    for x in myresult1:
        img = pygame.image.load('assets\objects' + x[1])
        display.blit(img, (x[3], x[4]))
        print(x[3])

def main_loop():
    my_objects = []
    pygame.event.clear()
    while not g_exit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    my_objects = get_objects()

        display.fill(colors.goldenrod)
        main_window()
        avatar(display_width / 2, main_window_height + 10)
        chat_window()
        controls_window()
        draw_objects(display, my_objects)
        pygame.display.update()
```